# Detecting android power button hits from a service

Tags: android, button, detect, listen

I'm trying to detect three consecutive hits from the android power button to start an activity from a background service ... I'm using the SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF actions to detect one hit from the power button.

The problem i'm facing is that I can't tell how much time elapses between two hits or between the first hit and the last hit. I'm using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() .. even though i'm hitting the button too fast .. the time difference doesn't make sense.  Sometimes it shows 800ms between two hits which is logical, but sometimes i get like 1290 ms and that is too long for two fast hits (I get the hit counts right)

Comment: Elapsed realtime doesn't give the time of the event, it gives the current time.  The system has a lot of other things to do at that time, it may just not get around to scheduling your app until then.

Comment: Thanks for your comment .. I used System.currentTimeMillis() .. and with some if statments .. I managed to do that

Comment: @user3396251 Can you share how you are performing the logic? I've managed to start the activity if the power button is clicked twice consecutively, but I can't manage if it is clicked 3 times or more than that.